# Facebook rejects a valid DoS'able vulnerability in WhatsApp - what should I do?

Tags: bug-bounty

I found a vulnerability in WhatsApp which allows the attacker to temporarily lock you out of your account (which results among other things in a loss of productivity e.g. stemming from a loss of the chat history).

I've reported it via Facebook's bug bounty program but it was rejected and the provided argument was wrong/incorrect/false. What's worse they closed the "ticket" without allowing me to refute their argument.

What should I do about that? I'm thinking of resumbitting it again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems DoS attacks are Out of Scope for a Facebook Bug Bounty program (https://www.facebook.com/whitehat). I'd wager your report was immediately rejected on that premise. If I were you, I wouldn't resubmit again.

Comment: I still did. Not because I'm stupid or persistent in my stupidity but because this attack can be carried out by a 3rd grader against tons of people. In fact this is how I lost access to my own account for a few days.

Comment: DoS is still out of scope, even if it's low skill attack.